# Apply Pipe to all Variable Occurrences in Controller

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs

I have a controller that has multiple requests (POST, GET etc.).
For all of them, in the path I have an id parameter. I want to validate that the parameter is a number string but I want to do it once and to have it apply to all.

Currently this is the code I have:

```
  @Get(':account_id')
  @ApiOperation({
    description: 'Get account information',
    operationId: 'getAccount',
    title: 'Get account information',
  })
  @ApiOkResponse({ type: AccountDto })
  @ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ type: ApiErrorDto })
  @ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: ApiErrorDto })
  @ApiNotFoundResponse({ type: ApiErrorDto })
  @ApiBadRequestResponse({ type: ApiErrorDto })
  @ApiImplicitParam({ name: 'account_id', description: 'The account Id' })
  async findOne(@Param('account_id', new ParseIntPipe()) accountId: string): Promise<AccountDto> {
    return await this.accountService.findOne(accountId);
  }
```

Every time I need to call the validation pipe.

Is there a way for me to apply validation to all account_id variables in my controller?

Comment: No, it is not supported. Why do you think it's a problem applying pipe multiple times - when needed?

Comment: I don't want to add a pipe every single time I use a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a class as your parameter and hava a validation on its properties.

Controller -

```
@Get(':id')
findOne(@Param() params: FindOneParams) {
  return params.id;
}
```

Class -

```
import { IsNumberString } from 'class-validator';

export class FindOneParams {
  @IsNumberString()
  id: number;
}
```